# bind dynamic expression in a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm creating a Vue application in which an expression will come from config as a variable. I need to run the expression (something like eval in javascript) and apply result to attribute

eg:

```
<v-text-field placeholder="{{expression}}"></v-text-field>
```

But this is showing the expression , not evaluating. Any way to achieve this?

Edit

---

Here expression can be something like

```
data.option=1?"ABC":"BCD"
```

Comment: Wait, why do you have 2 same accounts here?

Comment: I'm not having. I logged in on same from both mobile and laptop. I was unable to comment from my laptop so went back to mobile and tried. It's doing. Some stack overflow issue i doubt

Comment: You have 2 totally different accounts. Please use only one because it's forbidden and you may get one banned (maybe even both?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) but be aware::

```js
const out = 'data.option === 1 ? "ABC" : "BCD"'
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      data: {option: 1}
    }
  },
  computed: {
    expression() {
      return eval(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('this.' + out)))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-text-field :placeholder="expression"></v-text-field>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. But here const out=data.option==1? 'ABC':'BCD' is the try. But it shows the text. Not evaluating the expression. How to achieve this is the query

Comment: @Binesh Nambiar C hey mate, check again pls, I updated my answer :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer again. But the expression needs to fit in a variable(I'm planning to load the expression from server response in future which will set by admin).

Comment: Thanks Nikola, I will try with this. To a level what i'm looking for is this. Two way binding etc... need to verify on this though. Thanks for your great support

Comment: Hi Nikola, It worked well as expected. I used  
       var fn = new Function('dataObject', expr)
       return fn(this.dataObject)

instead eval since mozilla site suggested don't use eval. But ideally the logic is very much same. Thanks for your great help again. Even binding etc all are behaving as expected

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add colon before the property like following. To indicate that there is an expression in the middle of the quotation mark

```html
<v-text-field :placeholder="expression"></v-text-field>
```